# Struts 2 radio button in combination with displaytag

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag

I have following code in my JSP.

```
    <s:form  method="post" action="fetchFpfDataAction" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <s:textfield name="batchID" key="batchID" size="20" />
         <display:table id="fpfErrorTable" name="fpfErrorList" pagesize="5" cellpadding="5px;"
            cellspacing="5px;" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:20px;" uid="row" requestURI="">
        <display:column title="Row Number">
            <s:property value="#attr.row_rowNum"/>
        </display:column>
        <display:column property="batchNr" title="Batch Number"/>
        <display:column property="extnlRefNr" title="Claim Number"/>
        <display:column property="respMsgTx" title="Error Message"/>
        <display:column>
            <s:radio name="fpfErrorList[%{#attr.row_rowNum - 1}].errorType" list="errorTypes" value="%{#attr.fpfErrorTable.errorType}" theme="simple"></s:radio>
        </display:column>
        </display:table> 

        <s:submit value="FetchFPFData" align="center" theme="simple" />
        <s:submit value="UpdateFPFData" align="center" action="updateFpfDataAction" theme="simple"/> 
    </s:form>
```

i am able to select radio button choice and i could see my selection in Action class debug statements but while loading the same JSP again, radio button are displayed without any selection.

```
public String updateFpfData() {
        if(fpfErrorList != null && fpfErrorList.size() > 0) {
            for (FileProcessingRecordBean fpfError :fpfErrorList) {
                System.out.println("Claim Number "+fpfError.getExtnlRefNr());
                System.out.println("Error Type "+fpfError.getErrorType());
            }
        }

        return SUCCESS;
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="fetchFpfDataAction"
            class="fetchFpfDataAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success" type="tiles">
                /fpf.tiles
            </result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/fpf.tiles</result>
        </action>

        <action name="updateFpfDataAction"
            class="fetchFpfDataAction" method="updateFpfData">
            <interceptor-ref name="loggingStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success" type="tiles">
                /fpf.tiles
            </result>
            <result name="input" type="tiles">/fpf.tiles</result>
        </action>
```

Comment: What is the mapped result for SUCCESS in that action? A snippet of the corresponding struts.xml would help.

Comment: Looks ok. Could you try to add some <s:property> tags to the column where the radio button is, for %{#attr.fpfErrorTable.errorType} , %{#attr.fpfErrorTable} ?
Also, since fpfErrorTable is each row of the table I'd suggest renaming it to somehting more clear, like fpError/fpErrorRow...